# Using XSLT 1.0 to insert element in middle of XML List

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML 1.0 document that I need to transform with a XSLT 1.0 file.  The XML I need to transform looks like this:

```
<commandBarData guid="f3016f3c-2847-4557-b61a-a2d05319cf18">
  <menubar>
    <modeData guid="76d73481-9076-44c9-821c-52de9408cce2">
      <item guidRef="0f948c18-f326-40e5-9beb-2efc73803797"/>
      <item guidRef="6c91d5ab-d648-4364-96fb-3e71bcfaf70d"/>
      <item guidRef="71f8ffd6-46bd-43a3-8256-5412bc2d7741"/>
      <item guidRef="ac291790-gf51-d4s1-f23x-dsf9dfb6fgf5"/>
    </modeData>
  </menubar>
</commandBarData>
```

I need to insert `<item guidRef="21c1f231-e03e-48e8-916a-d8790442b417"/>` after the element `<item guidRef="0f948c18-f326-40e5-9beb-2efc73803797"/>`

So the list will look like this:

```
<commandBarData guid="f3016f3c-2847-4557-b61a-a2d05319cf18">
  <menubar>
    <modeData guid="76d73481-9076-44c9-821c-52de9408cce2">
      <item guidRef="0f948c18-f326-40e5-9beb-2efc73803797"/>
      <item guidRef="21c1f231-e03e-48e8-916a-d8790442b417"/>
      <item guidRef="6c91d5ab-d648-4364-96fb-3e71bcfaf70d"/>
      <item guidRef="71f8ffd6-46bd-43a3-8256-5412bc2d7741"/>
      <item guidRef="ac291790-gf51-d4s1-f23x-dsf9dfb6fgf5"/>
    </modeData>
  </menubar>
</commandBarData>
```

How do I do this using XSLT 1.0?

I have made several attempts and now I have code that is mostly working. The one issue remaining is how to insert the element after. The code below works except...

```
<xsl:template match="uiConfig/commandBars"> 
  <xsl:copy> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select = "node()|@*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template
```

match="uiConfig/commandBars/commandBarData/menubar/modeData/item[@guidRef='0f948c18-f326-40e5-9beb-2efc73803797']">

It generates this xml:

```
<item guidRef="0f948c18-f326-40e5-9beb-2efc73803797"><item guidRef="21c1f231-e03e-48e8-916a-d8790442b417" xmlns:frmwrk="Corel Framework Data" /></item>
      <item guidRef="21c1f231-e03e-48e8-916a-d8790442b417" />
      <item guidRef="6c91d5ab-d648-4364-96fb-3e71bcfaf70d" />
      <item guidRef="71f8ffd6-46bd-43a3-8256-5412bc2d7741" />
      <item guidRef="ac291790-gf51-d4s1-f23x-dsf9dfb6fgf5" />
```

How do I make it append after the element and not insert as a child?

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with this? Post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Normally, I would do that. My issue so far is that I have very little familiarity with xslt so my attempts so far are way off base and not even close.  I will add them anyways.

Comment: If you need a starting point, start with an [identity transform](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying) and then add another template that matches `item[@guidRef='0f948c18-f326-40e5-9beb-2efc73803797']`. That template should make a copy of the current `item` and also create the new `item`.

Comment: @DanielHaley I already have the `<xsl:template match="uiConfig/commandBars">  <xsl:copy>     <xsl:apply-templates select = "node()|@*" />` code. I am lost specifically with how to match on the item and insert after it.

Comment: @BenHoffman There is no `except` operator in XSLT 1.0. I suggest you follow Daniel Haley's advice to the letter.

Comment: @michael.hor257k That was very helpful, especially the match tag. One issue though is that the xslt has an issue with the guid. I am now getting the error `Expected end of the expression, found '‌'.
...18-f326-40e5-9beb-2efc73803797'] -->‌<-- ​` with the guid in my attempted solution above.

Comment: You seem to have some invisible characters between `]` and `"`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k there was definitely some kind of hidden element!

Comment: Re your other problem: insert the new item after closing `xsl:copy`, not inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked:

```
<xsl:template match="uiConfig/commandBars/commandBarData/menubar/modeData/item[@guidRef='0f948c18-f326-40e5-9beb-2efc73803797']">
  <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
  </xsl:copy>
  <item guidRef="21c1f231-e03e-48e8-916a-d8790442b417"/>
</xsl:template>
```